# How to trigger emulate click ngClick from jQuery

Tags: angularjs

How have a link like

```
<a href="" ng-click="someAction()">Some text</a>
```

and I want to invoke `ngClick`action from jQuery:

```
$('a').click()
```

But it doesn't work: `someAction()` not invoked. Also didn't work

```
$('a').trigger('click')
```

Is it possible to invoke `someAction()` from jQuery?

Comment: im not sure if i understand you, but you can triggering a click with `.trigger('click');` or `.triggerHandler('click');`

Comment: @AdrianPreuss, `trigger('click')` also doesn't work

Comment: why you need to invoke function from jquery , i will suggest to use angular way itself.

Comment: @prash, It's requirement of functional testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nevermind the apply cycles and timeouts, here you are:

```
$('a').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
 'view': window,
 'bubbles': true,
 'cancelable': true
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I need to do it outside angular, I can't change source code, just need to test from jquery

Comment: You can run those commands from javascript console, so you are essentially outside angular (`angular` is a global variable exposed by AngularJS on a window object)

Comment: I have an error `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: that means that the angular application was already in the middle of the $digest cycle. were you doing anything else that was causing UI updates?

Comment: I added a safer apply

Comment: I think, there is a directive, that listens clicking by this link and show some template. is it a problem?

Comment: hm, again `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`.

Sorry, I'm new to angular and just want to make click like in jquery

Comment: so you ran the my latest version that has a phase variable?

Comment: >>so you ran the my latest version that has a phase variable? 
yes

Comment: I think you may simply need to break out from the $apply cycle, try my new approach

Comment: Tried also you last variant, nothing happends

Comment: Ok, i got it working, for some weird triggerHandler and trigger functions did not work on it, had to get down and dirty and dispatch a mouse event on the element

Comment: ok, it works, thanks for your attention and help, angular isn't simple framework :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's strange that it's not working, I get it working with both

```
angular.element('a[ng-click="someAction()"]')
```

and

```
$('a[ng-click="someAction()"]')
```

as selectors, and both `click()` and `trigger('click')` to fire the clickhandler.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/6VMavwVImXAonSp8xZrI?p=preview
(Watch the console)

Comment: Awesome. The first one helped me out after a lot of head scratching.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me the old way
`document.querySelector('a.btn.btn-info.showmore.ng-scope').click()`

Comment: The old good vanilla JS, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could, but you should assign an id:

```
<a id='Button'>SOMETEXT</a>

$("#Button").click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
   someAction();
);
```

This should fix it.