# Check-All checkbox do not change the ng-model

Tags: jquery, angular, checkbox

I used this jquery for a check-all checkbox that when clicked all of the checkboxes will be ticked:

```
function checkAll(e) {
    var check = $(e).is(':checked');
    if (check) {
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
    }
    else {
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
    }
}
```

But it has a problem, I set the angular function for ng-click of checkboxes that changing ng-model according to the some condition, and if selected checkboxes more than a number the ng-model becoming null, it is working when I click checkboxes individually but when I am using check-all checkbox that ng-model do not becoming null and still has a value!!!

I tried various solutions, but any of them has a same result.

What is going wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be another way to handle it instead of merging both jquery and angular, simply make use of angular to do it.

The below code is going to use a field within the object to manage the model's state in the HTML like so

For example

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'World';
      $scope.items = [
     {name: 'Field one', checked:false},
     {name:'Field two', checked:true},
     {name:'Field three', checked: false},
     {name: 'Field four', checked: true}
      ];
     $scope.checkall = false;
      
      $scope.toggleAll = function(checked){
       angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
         item.checked = checked
       });
      }
      
      // listen to when the others were clicked or not
     $scope.checkboxClicked = function (item, value){
       if(value === false){
       $scope.checkall = false
      }else{
      $scope.checkall = true
        // check the others to see if you need to make check all true or not
        angular.forEach($scope.items, function(x){
         if(x.checked !== true && x.name !== item.name){
          $scope.checkall = false
         }
       });
      }
     }
      
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

     <body  ng-app="plunker">
     <div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleAll($event.target.checked)" ng-model="checkall"> Check all --{{checkall}}
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type='checkbox' ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="checkboxClicked(item, $event.target.checked)"> {{item.name}}-- {{item.checked}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KusoZ1zrYDd8QjyL7Cou?p=preview)
Consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777980/6517383
You can dispatch Event to handle angular cycles.

```
$('a').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {
  'view': window,
  'bubbles': true,
  'cancelable': true
}));
```

And do it like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/17110709/6517383

```
function checkAll(e) {
    var check = $(e).is(':checked');
    if (check) {
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('click');
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('change');
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:not(:checked)').trigger('input'); 
    }
    else {
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:checked').trigger('click');
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:checked').trigger('change');
        $('[name="row_Checkbox"]:checked').trigger('input'); 
    }

}
```

Other answers on this thread my be more helpful [Update Angular model after setting input value with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109850/update-angular-model-after-setting-input-value-with-jquery)